# Ipython is using python 3.5 instead of 2.7

Tags: python, 16.04, ipython

I recently update my system from 15.10 to 16.04 but now I'm having a problem with the interpreter used by ipython.

Now ipython a ipython3 uses the same version (3.5.1)

I have tried reinstalling ipython but the problem persist.

Here are the versions reported by the console:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160330] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

```
$ ipython
Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

```
$ ipython3
Python 3.5.1+ (default, Mar 30 2016, 22:46:26) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Comment: How did you install IPyton? What's the output of `type -a ipython` and `type -a ipython3`?

Comment: I installed them both with apt.

$type -a ipython
ipython is /usr/local/bin/ipython
ipython is /usr/bin/ipython

$ type -a ipython3
ipython3 is /usr/local/bin/ipython3
ipython3 is /usr/bin/ipython3

Comment: `ipython is /usr/local/bin/ipython` – presumably you have a different IPython in `/usr/local/bin` in addition to the one `/usr/bin`. The latter was likely installed by the package manager. What's the output of `/usr/bin/ipython <&- | head -n 1` and `/usr/bin/ipython3 <&- | head -n 1`?

Comment: Images?... If you are talking about the format of my question it was edited, you can can check history.

Comment: There are different installed files for ipython but they are the same version. Here is the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24029040/  I have already solved the problem editing the first line of /usr/local/bin/ipython to "#!/usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line of /usr/local/bin/ipython is "#!/usr/bin/python3" I could edit that line to use python instead of python3 or it was as simple as run with:

```
python /usr/local/bin/ipython
```

Comment: When I tried, that, I got: `ImportError: No module named IPython`.

Comment: Have you installed the package ipython?... or may be could be an installation issue. With some packages I get problems with pip, normally if the package is on the Ubuntu repository I prefer to install them from there.  `sudo apt install ipython`

Answer (score 6):

I found it best to do:

`which ipython`

This shows the location of your ipython file that gets run when you type `ipython`.  Then edit that (I used gedit: `sudo gedit /usr/local/ipython`, or whatever path you get from `which ipython`).  Then change the  first line to use the python version you want.  E.g. if you want python3.5, change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python3.5`.

Answer (score 2):

Install latest version of the iPython for the Python 3 using the pip (recommend)

```
$ sudo pip3 install ipython
```

For run the installed iPython for the Python 3 use:

```
$ python3 `which ipython3`
```

or straightforward

```
$ ipython3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a good idea to move to python3, but if you want to use python 2.7 instead, you can move using anaconda.

Comment: I'm agree is better to use python3, but I'm trying to learn something about bazaar plugins and it uses python2... Until 15.10 I could use the two different interpreters with ipython and ipython3.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall it using following command and it will unlink:

1. make sure you pip is also working in python2 if not do following:

   `sudo python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip`
2. Once pip is unlinked from python3 then do following to unlink ipython from python3 as well:

   `sudo python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall ipython`

Comment: now IPython 6.0+ does not support Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, or 3.2. When using Python 2.7, please install IPython 5.x LTS Long Term Support version.